# Thickbox 3.1 IE8 scrolling problem

Tags: html, css, thickbox

Having a slight problem with 
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

In IE8, the overlay window doesn't scroll when you scroll down in the browser.  So if you click something at the bottom of the browser window, the overlay window pops up but at the top of the screen so you have to scroll back up.  This only happens in IE8, all other browsers the overlay window follows.  Help? Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce this in IE8. Is there a specific demo on the page that shows this behavior?

Comment: i don't understand the problem, please clarify. i've used thickbox extensively over the past few months; are you referring to the problem of the overlay not covering the bottom of very long pages or losing scroll position. The first is a css height problem and the second a javascript issue. Both can be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but only when using `<frames>` or `<iframes>`. Being unable to correct the problem, along with a few other bugs, I decided switch to using Shadowbox http://www.shadowbox-js.com/. I found it to be ALOT more flexible. Just a suggestion. But as for the IE8 problem you reported, I never encountered the issue in a parent window, just when using frames.